# Does $\operatorname{trace}(A_n^\dagger C_n^TBC_n)$ tend to infinity as $\|A_n\|_F$ and $\|C_n\|_F$ tend to infinity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been reading a paper and trying to understand a result regarding the existence of finite minimisers of some functional $S(C, A): \mathbb{R}^{n \times T}\times \mathbb{S}^{T}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$. The functional involves a number of terms but specifically of interest are $\operatorname{trace}(A^\dagger \hat{C}^TB\hat{C})$ and $F(A)$. Here $F: \mathbb{S}^{T}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$is convex and coercive, $A\in\mathbb{S}^{T}_+$ is positive semi-definite, $B\in\mathbb{S}^{T}_+$ is an arbitrary positive semi-definite matrix and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times T}$.

The authors consider a generic minimising sequence $\{(C_n, A_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $S(C_n, A_n)\rightarrow \inf_{C, A} S(C, A)$. Each $C_n$ can be expressed as $C_n = \hat{C}_n + C^\star_n$ where the columns of $\hat{C}_n$ belong to the range of $B$ and the columns of $C^\star_n$ belong to its nullspace. They conclude that $S(C_n, A_n) = S(\hat{C}_n, A_n)$ (which I perfectly understand). However, they go on to say that the sequence $(\hat{C}_n, A_n)$ is bounded since, if it were not, the coercive penalty $F$ or the term $trace(A_n^\dagger \hat{C_n}^TB\hat{C_n})$ would tend to infinity as $n$ grows. The coercive penalty tending to infinity makes sense, but I don't see how the trace term could also tend to infinity.

Does $\operatorname{trace}(A_n^\dagger \hat{C_n}^TB\hat{C_n})$ tend to infinity as $\|A_n\|_F$ and $\|\hat{C}_n\|_F$ tend to infinity? If so, why?

Here, $A^\dagger$ is the moore-penrose psuedo inverse of $A$.

Comment: Could you provide us with some context? Why are you interested in this problem?

Comment: Hi, of course. I'll edit my post.

Comment: What about $n=T$ and $C=0$? Then the trace in question is just zero.

Comment: What does it mean "$C$ belongs to the range of $B$"?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have edited my post regarding your range question. We can disregard the trivial solution $\hat{C}_n = 0$ since this represents some optimisation problem in which $\hat{C}_n = 0$ would not be the optimal solution.

Comment: Ok, now it looks much more interesting :) I'll think about it